# Converting rows into columns and vice versa for part of table in oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle10g, pivot

I have a table output as follows:

```
class | student | week | eng |  maths | science
  1   |   stu1  |   1  | 67  |   78   |     89
  1   |   stu2  |   1  | 78  |   88   |     90
  1   |   stu3  |   1  | 45  |   34   |     45
  1   |   stu1  |   2  | 67  |   45   |     34
```

And I need final output as :

```
class | student |   sub   |  week1 |    week2
  1   |   stu1  |   eng   |     67 |    67
  1   |   stu1  |   maths |     78 |    45
  1   |   stu1  | science |     89 |    34
  1   |   stu2  |   eng   |     78 |    89
  1   |   stu2  |   maths |     88 |    90
  1   |   stu2  | science |     90 |    89
  1   |   stu3  |   eng   |     45 |    
  1   |   stu3  |   maths |     34 |    
  1   |   stu3  | science |     45 |
```

That is in the table, for only a part, rows are turned into columns and columns are converted into rows.

I am using oracle 10g.

Here is my query for 1st table.

```
select class, student,
to_char(dt,'WW') as week,
sum(case when sm.sub='eng' then 'eng' end) as eng,
sum(case when sm.sub='maths' then 'maths' end) as maths,
sum(case when sm.sub='science' then 'science' end) as science
from studentList sl left join studentMarks sm
on sl.stId=sm.stId
group by class, student, to_char(dt,'WW')
order by class, student;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PIVOT/UNPIVOT operator for this. Please find one good article here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Hi I am using oracle 10g. PIVOT and UNPIVOT is not supported in 10g.

Comment: may be this can help you:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/eac0691a-b562-450a-a522-377bbd79e14d/pivoting?forum=transactsql